# Set permission of a file in a pod

Tags: kubernetes

We are creating a file in a pod which should be only readable by process running in a pod. Is there a way to restrict the access of a file so that only pod can read the content of the file ?

Comment: As opposed to what? Users on the Node? Other containers within the Pod? Other containers on the Node? The NSA?

Comment: By virtue of running it in a container, unless you've explicitly specified external storage, nothing else can read its filesystem.  What's a specific case you're trying to prevent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While building the container you can

1. create a user.

   RUN useradd -ms /bin/bash newuser
2. Change the ownership of file

chown "username" "filename"

3. Change the permissions of the file so that only the created user has access to file.

chmod 600 "filename"

4. Specify the container startup script to run as newly created user